# Visual Studio emulators not showing up

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have `visual studio 2015 Community` installed. I also have `Microsoft Emulator for windows 10` installed. However the Studio is showing only "Start" instead of any simulators list.

When i press Start, i get error

"The project needs to be deployed before it can be started".

How can i setup the emulators list.

I am using x86, x64 shows the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be several problems. First I suggest you read [this](https://onestopdotnet.wordpress.com/2015/08/10/xamarin-vs-2015-break-the-error-message-into-chunks/). If it doesnt work then check if your emulators are setup correctly read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/somasegar/2015/07/29/building-apps-for-windows-10-with-visual-studio-2015/) for the setup.